# How to modify user account in FBA authentication

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

I have an installation of Sharepoint Foundation 2010 configured in Mixed Authentication (Windows + Form Based).

I would like to know how to modify the account of a FBA user like this one

```
i:0#.f|fbamembershipprovider|name1.surname1
```

into, for example

```
i:0#.f|fbamembershipprovider|name2.surname2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able doing this using *stsadm*:

```
stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin "i:0#.f|fbamembershipprovider|name1.surname1" -newlogin "i:0#.f|fbamembershipprovider|name2.surname2" -ignoresidhistory
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have SP2010 August CU then you can add custom code into the MigrateUser() command. Read this post by Steve "Claims" Peschka: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2011/01/27/migrating-user-accounts-from-windows-claims-to-saml-claims.aspx

I have not yet tried it but the sample in the post (with some minor tweaks) could probably be used in your case.